# Python typeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, list

I have this code

```
a = [0.0, 1.1, 2.2]
b = a * 2.0
```

and that is where I get the error

```
typeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

what I want it to `return` is

```
b = [0.0, 2.2, 4.4]
```

Comment: Remember to accept an answer. See this pic http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 6):

The error is that you are multiplying a list, that is `a` and a float, that is `2.0`.

Do this instead (a list comprehension)

```
b = [i*2.0 for i in a]
```

A small demo

```
>>> a = [0.0, 1.1, 2.2]
>>> b = [i*2.0 for i in a]
>>> b
[0.0, 2.2, 4.4]
```

Using `map`

```
map(lambda x:x*2.0 , a)
```

Here are the `timeit` results

```
bhargav@bhargav:~$ python -m timeit "a = [0.0, 1.1, 2.2]; b = [i*2.0 for i in a]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.34 usec per loop
bhargav@bhargav:~$ python -m timeit "a = [0.0, 1.1, 2.2]; b = map(lambda x:x*2.0 , a)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.686 usec per loop
bhargav@bhargav:~$ python -m timeit "import numpy; a = numpy.array([0.0, 1.1, 2.2]); b = a * 2.0"
10 loops, best of 3: 5.51 usec per loop
```

The list comprehension is the fastest.

Comment: Is here any way that I can do this without a for loop?  Is there a way that I can write; a ; so that I can operate on the entire array?

Comment: @MarkAisenberg Using `map` or by using `numpy`. The previous is preffered

Comment: But why do you not want a `for` loop. It is the best

Comment: Using `map` and `lambda` is unlikely to be faster than `list comprehension`.

Comment: @MarkAisenberg: Note what happens if you do `a * 2`: it doubles the list, not its elements.

Comment: @Akavall Yep! I added the timeit results also. `lambda` the trouble-maker

Comment: Thanks for the timeit results. For the record (although it is not related to the OP's question), numpy is "penalized" in those benches because the array creation is taken into account. On a purely numpy-based program, where the data is already available as numpy arrays, and for larger arrays, numpy gets better. I get results comparable to accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708783/numpy-vs-list-comprehension-which-is-faster).

Comment: Certainly @Jérôme I understand that! That was the reason why I hadn't put the `numpy` stuff at first. Then I was asked to put the other answer's (i.e. yours) timing stuff too. It is inaccurate to calculate in that way actually. I personally liked your answer because you explicitly mention that it is *faster for large lists*. Anyway it is left for the OP to decide as to which he likes the best. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do element-wise operations on lists.

Using list comprehensions:

```
a = [0.0, 1.1, 2.2]
b = [2 * i for i in a]
```

Using numpy (faster for large lists):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.0, 1.1, 2.2])
b = a * 2.0
```

(then you get a numpy array, not a list)