# Numpy Array vs. Python list running time

Tags: python, arrays, performance, list, numpy

So I do realize that Numpy Arrays are more compact than Python lists.
But how about running time? 
How do all operations like add and remove compare in terms of both time complexity and actual running time?

Comment: Did you try a performance benchmark?

Comment: Use the timeit module and get your desired results easily: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html

Comment: They cost about the same. Both are contiguous arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy vs list comprehension, which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708783/numpy-vs-list-comprehension-which-is-faster)

Comment: A python list contains pointers to objects elsewhere in memory. Its data is not contiguous.

Comment: Compiled numpy operations are faster, but creating arrays has a significant overhead.  So time comparisons depend on the size of the problem, and what the starting point is.